# PHP: Uploading troubles

Tags: php, upload

I'm making a image uploader but I have come across 2 errors. Which are:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/Corgi 007.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stationr/public_html/admin/doupload.php on line 12

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/chroot/tmp/phpMvRSbS' to 'upload/Corgi 007.jpg' in /home/stationr/public_html/admin/doupload.php on line 12
```

The errors are occuring when I call the move_uploaded_file() method. Here is my code (note this has no error checking what so ever it is just bare ones uploading).

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/$filename");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've failed to check if the upload succeeded at all:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   move file ...
} else {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

As well, is there a "upload" subdirectory in whatever your script's current working directory is? Does the web server process have write permissions on that directory?

And as a MAJOR security hole, blindlly using the `['name']` parameter of the upload as your target filename allows a malicious user to scribble on ANY file on your server. Never ever blindly use that filename. If the upload filename is provided as (say) `../../../../../../etc/passwd`, you've now allowed someone to replace your system password file.

Comment: Oh man, that is embarrassing.. In my haste I completely forgot to add "../" to the destination folder. And yea I know all about the security side of the uploading (The uploader is only accessible by admin login which is also secure). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't go with security by obscurity. If someone does manage to hack/bypass the login, you still shouldn't provide them with the tools to trash your server. Make them fight for every bit of ground they can gain.